# Why form is not rendered?

Tags: laravel-4

I have just installed laravel 4, in my create view, the form is not rendered, instead I get:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'license.store')) }}
```

even, if I used `<?php` instead of `{{`, nothing will be rendered into HTML

Any idea pleas?

Comment: Can you share more code? some code from controller and view.

Comment: I had to add blade into file name ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your filename have .blade in it? For example: `create.blade.php`.

The `{{ }}` notation is a part of Laravel's Blade Templating system. In order to do what you're hoping for you'd need to rename that file to `create.blade.php`.

Don't worry about editing your View::make() call in the controller though. Laravel detects that in the filename.

More info on Laravel's Blade Template system: [laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)